# cloud run returns 502 for SEARCH request verb

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

i am using SEARCH because i would like the equivalent of GET (idempotent) but with a request body. this is because i'd rather submit my request body as JSON instead of serializing to URL query parameters.

i'm making requests to a cloud run service, but i don't see my requests in my service logs. however, the requests are coming through a cloud load balancer, and there, i *do* see the requests, with `statusDetails: "response_sent_by_backend"` which [google says](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/troubleshooting-ext-https-lbs) means the load balancer is not generating the response.

so, somewhere between the LB and my service, something else returns a 502, but I can't find any logs about it. anyone know how to trouble-shoot? alternatively, is there something else i can do to make GET-style requests with a JSON body?

Answer (score 1):

Welp, I haven't heard anything. I wanted to try using `QUERY` instead of search, since it looks like `QUERY` is [IETF-standards-track for an idempotent method with a body](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-safe-method-w-body-02.html), but my backend is a nodejs express server, and express does not support `QUERY`. So, I couldn't test whether or not Google's infra supports `QUERY`.

Instead, I changed my `SEARCH` requests to `PUT`, since at least `PUT` is considered idempotent, even if it's not considered safe. I added a `X-HTTP-Method-Override: SEARCH` header to my new `PUT` requests, and then used the [method-override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override) package to rewrite them back to `SEARCH` so I didn't have to change my controllers:

```js
  app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override', { methods: ['PUT'] }))
```

This seems to satisfy both google's load balancing infra and express, so I'm sticking with it for now until the relevant IETF standards advance.